# Custom Taxonomy Permalinks Redirection

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, functions, redirect

I have set up a custom taxonomy on a custom post type using the following: (For the sake of example, the custom post type is called `newtype` and the new taxonomy is just called `newtax`.

```
// Create Custom Post Type for newpost
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'x_newtype',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'New Type' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'New Type' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'newtype'),
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','thumbnail')
        )
    );
}


// Add custom field for custom post type
function new_taxonomy() {
   register_taxonomy(
    'newtax',
    'x_newtype',
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'label' => 'New Tax',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'newtax')
    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'new_taxonomy' );
```

This works fine, but I had a question in regards to the URL redirecting.

Currently, if you go to `http://www.domain.com/newtype/newtax-term/post-name/` it will redirect to `http://www.domain.com/newtype/post-name/` .  What is the best way to allow `http://www.domain.com/newtype/newtax-term/post-name/` to load, without redirecting?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: have you flushed your permalinks after setting: `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'newtax')` ?

Comment: The permalink cache has been flushed by visiting Settings --> Permalinks --> Save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way to allow `http://www.domain.com/newtype/newtax-term/post-name/` to load, without redirecting?

You have to add a custom rewrite rule to make this work. Otherwise WordPress doesn't understand the `newtax-term` part of your permalink structure and redirects you to the URL which it does understand, which is `%post_type%/%post_slug%`.

If you want to understand how WordPress Rewrite API works, I would recommend you to read [The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) article. Spare no effort to learn it and you won't have issues with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  And I'm going to assume you mean `/%post-slug%/` ;) Either way, the Rewrite API link looks like it will be very useful.